# Always center heading, input and submit-button on a page

Tags: html, css, position, center

I know this is probably one of the most beginner questions. I am just trying to re-learn a little bit of CSS and I want to start with some good practices.

I would like to create a really, really simple page with only one heading and an input box.

I have some html that looks like this:

```
    <body>
        <h1>Heading 1</h1>
        <div class="box">
            <div class="box-child">
                <input type="text" name="name" value="value" class="btn">
            </div>
            <div class="box-child">
                <input type="submit" value="send to some database" class="inp">
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

and some random css that looks like this:

```
html {
    position: relative;
    top: 40%;
    left: 40%;
}



.box {}

.box-child{}

.btn {}

.inp{}
```

I use the entire `html` element to set the positioning. I know this is horrible and not at all near any kind of good practice. But when a beginner like me sees that it puts things in the center of the page, it first looks like it works.

This results in this:

[image]

Now I am not asking only for solutions, but to any kind of resource. Maybe also other answers here on SO. I just really wanted to make sure that I can solve this super easy task with an approach that is rather flexible and could be considered good practice.

Answer (score 0):

**Check this out this is what you wanted??**

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  
  /* grid-method */
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  
  /* flex-method */
  /* display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center; */
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1> Simple Input and Button </h1>
  <br /> <!--for spacing-->
  <input type="text" />
  <button type="submit"> Submit </button>
</div>
```

You can change elements styles accordingly or as you want.